# Flatten a Tree into an Array

Tags: c, arrays, tree

I am looking for the best way to place a tree into an array

The idea is to follow this principle : [Array Implementation of Trees](http://www.vias.org/cppcourse/chap21_10.html)
but I'am stuck on how to know what nodes are the children and what nodes are at the same level, because I'am not using a binary tree.

I might have to store ASCII but I can't simply allow arrays of 256 pointers !

Any idea would be welcome.

The purpose of this, is to send an array (tree) to my GPU, instead of using structures.

Comment: Just replace (conceptually) pointers by array indexes.

Comment: "I'am not using a binary tree" - Then, what kind of tree are you using? What are the leaf objects in your tree?

Comment: Hanno Binder Well, I'am using a simple tree of words, so at the moment 26 letters, but I would like to use ascii in the future so potentially 256 children from the root. @BasileStarynkevitch, well that would probably work, I would then place my structs into my array and replace the pointers ?

Comment: How long will your words be? Or, how deep will your tree become? - You may want to trade in some of the width of the tree for depth.

Comment: well the maximum length of patten could be 128 chars. I'm planning to reduce the tree at some point :) but I need first to place it in an array to send it to the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my idea of `converting tree into an array`.

Take an array of size `MAX_VAL`, which is the total number of nodes in the tree. The type of the array should be same as that of a node but with one extra field. Its the index value for its parent. You store each node in this way. Store the root node at first position. Say `1`. Now the child nodes of this node are stored subsequently with the extra field storing `1` (since this was where root was stored).

Apply this procedure on all nodes and you are done. You can get back the tree, by a simple recursive call on each node.

Hope this helps. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Ahnentafel lists are very big if not near-perfectly balanced. My guess is your tree isn't going to be balanced, so the benefit of implicit parent/child pointers will outweigh the cost. I'm never seen a non-binary Ahnentafel list, but I assume it's possible (were you asking for the implicit equations?).

Could you keep a sorted list of child pointers for each node (ASCII character + pointer/index)? In this case it might be best, as others suggest, to construct the tree using pointers and allow the children to grow. Then pack all the nodes into a list: work out an order to place the nodes, use prefix sums for their offsets into the array, store the position indices on each node and finally copy the children lists into the array (replacing the children pointers with list indices can be done by following the pointers and querying the index from the previous step).

Traversing to a child in CUDA won't be constant time, but since the order is know you can use a binary search to speed things up.